# Can viruses jump from a portable windows install to my main internal install?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, virus

I used Rufus to create a Windows 11 To Go -install on an external hard drive while Windows 10 remains on my main drive that is internally plugged in to my computer to dual boot between them.

Notably when installing I used the **prevent windows from accessing internal disks** which i think edits a part of external windows install so that it cannot read/write to other disks. This option stops it from updating the Windows 10 partitions so that I can unplug the drive and keep using Windows 10 on my internal.

The question is if untrusted software that had a virus of some sort were run on the external Windows 11 install could it make its way to my internal Windows 10 install? Excluding viruses that transfer over WiFi I would also be unplugging the external drive when booting into the internal drive.

The installs are on two separate drives but they are both plugged in at the same time although in the Windows 11 OS I cant see other drives, I can only see the Windows 11 drive in the Disk Management.  I assume that means they are completely isolated?

Comment: Portable Windows (Windows to Go) is not supported on Windows 10 and I do not think available on Windows 11 (USB will not have the required booting requirements). If you could succeed, Ransomware can make the jump.

Comment: im confused since it does work and im able to plug in my windows 11 drive and boot windows 11 then unplug it and boot windows 10

Comment: Is the portable installation of Windows networked to the physical installation of Windows?

Comment: What do you mean by that? are both drives plugged in at the same time or networked as in internet net work

Comment: If the external Win11 is _completely isolated_ from the internal Win10, i.e. has _absolutely no access_ to the internal drive, I don't see a way for viruses to jump. If they use the same boot sector on the internal drive, a virus could be transmitted from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply the installs are on two separate drives but they are both plugged in at the same time although in the windows 11 os i cant see other drives i can only see the windows 11 drive in the disk management so i assume that means they are completely isolated?

Comment: If your initial question prompts some clarifying questions or requests for further info, please don't answer in comments. Rather [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1768728/edit) your question instead. That way everything relevant is directly available for community members. No need to bother now, I did it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The *"prevent windows from accessing internal disks"* option only **asks** Windows to not make the drives available to the user the drive by turning on a specific option. But it does not magically make the drive disappear from the system, which means that, a determined attacker or malware should have no trouble altering its content.

For your reference, what the feature you describe does is set the `SanPolicy` value to `4` during the `offlineServicing` pass of Windows, as described in [this official *Windows To Go* creation guide by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-8.1-and-8/jj721578(v=ws.11)), which, per the guide:

> prevent(s) the operating system from automatically bringing online any internally connected disk.

So, all it does, really, is set the drives **offline** in Windows, but it does not actually remove them from the system, and therefore, it should be relatively trivial for malware to temporarily bring the drive back online to write to it (if that's even needed, as my guess is that you can probably still write to disk from Windows without bringing it online).

Please bear in mind that on any Windows system, you can use disk manager or PowerShell or the Windows internal APIs to switch a drive between online and offline, so you really shouldn't rely on offline feature to keep you away from malware. The only **SAFE** way of ensuring that a disk will not be accessed is to physically disconnect it.

Comment: i see so in that case you suggest i unplug all drives before booting into the external drive thanks for the reply is there any other precautions i should take while running my external install?

Comment: Well, theoretically, malware could replace or slipstream some malicious payload in your UEFI firmware, so that even if you had your disk disconnected, you could still get infected, so the only advice I have, if you are planning to run "dodgy" software is to use a machine that you don't care about and intend to lose, because advanced malware infections are no longer disk-based only, and with intel and AMD hiding closed source **modifiable** execution code (Management Engine) in the CPU itself, that runs in parallel to the OS, there's no telling what kind of nasty thing advanced malware can do.